# Normal coordinates and the metric tensor

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I was wondering whether the metric tensor in normal coordinates can be expressed somehow in terms of the exponential map. Cause I just don't see how the metric in normal coordinates is actually defined.

My intuition tells me that since $exp$ is a parametrisation of the manifold (locally), the metric is defined by $(g_{i,j}):=(Dexp)^T Dexp$ is this correct?

Comment: The expression involves the Riemannian curvature and is called Riemann formula. You can find a discussione here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185527/riemanns-formula-for-the-metric-in-a-normal-neighborhood

Comment: @N.Ciccoli but this is only a Taylor expansion and not really a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p \in M$. Recall that normal coordinates about $p$ map a neighbourhood of the  identity in $T_{p}M$ to a neighbourhood of $p$ via the exponential map $exp|_{p}$. The metric in normal coordinates is defined (e.g. in the context of the Gauss lemma) by taking polar coordinates on $T_{p}M$ and noting that for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small there is a diffeomorphism

$\begin{align} f: (0,\epsilon)\times S^n & \to B \\  
(r,v) & \mapsto exp|_{p}(rv) \end{align}$

The resulting chart defines so-called *geodesic polar coordinates* about $p$. We can also define the *geodesic spheres* $\Sigma_{r} := f(S^n(r))$. Gauss's Lemma states that locally, geodesic spheres are orthogonal to geodesics, and it follows that the metric near p can be written as
$$ g = dr^2 + h(r,v)$$
where $h$ is the restriction of $g$ to $\Sigma_r$. Note that since h is positive definite it is immediately clear that geodesics (which are purely radial in normal coordinates) locally minimise path length.

There is of course no *unique* definition of normal coordinates; they are defined up to a change of basis on $T_{p}M$. Physicists like to fix *local inertial coordinates* at $p$ by choosing normal coordinates with the additional condition $g_{ab}|_{p} = \eta_{ab}$, but this is a matter of taste. It is worth noting that in the Lorentzian case, Gauss's lemma no longer applies; for example, geodesics can locally *maximise* their length.